# GetMousePosition return always 0

Tags: vtk

I have a simple question: why the following code:

```
int p[2] = {0, 0};
vtkRenderWindow->GetInteractor()->GetMousePosition(&p[0], &p[1]);
TRACE("Mouse position: %d.%d\n", p[0], p[1]);
```

gave me always Mouse position: 0.0 ?

It means a lot for me if I solve this problem !!! Could you help me a little bit, please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally the event position of the interactor is always updated on events like MouseMove, MouseWheelForward, etc.

So if you create your own interactor style and handle the MouseWheelForwardEvt, then you get the current position of the mouse cursor within the renderer by querying the event position.

Additionally you should make sure, the the RenderWindow has the focus, when you scroll the MouseWheel otherwise the event is not recognized.

A good example for your own interactor style can be found here [VTK MouseEvents](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/MouseEvents)

Based on the example in the link, your MouseWheelForwardEvt could look like this (assuming `vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera` is used).

```
virtual void OnMouseWheelForwardEvt()
{
     myInteractor->GetEventPosition(x,y);
     //do more stuff

     //forward the event
     vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera::OnMouseWheelForwardEvt();

}
```

Comment: Like always, you helped me a lot ! :)

Comment: Yes, I don't forwarding the mouse wheel message, because I don't want to made zoom on mouse wheel ... I want to do something else ...

Comment: But I do have a little question: how can I avoid zomming on mouse wheel message, as long I let the forwarding mouse wheel event ? Is it possible ?

Comment: I don't think that you have to necessarily forward the event to the superclass, so the main functionality is not processed.